# Twitter4j API location filter not working

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I am using the Twitter4j API to connect to the public fire-hose. I am trying to get Tweets specific to locations or keywords but it just doesn't seem to work.Here's my code:

```
String geoInfo = "37.7833,122.4167"; //Coordinates of San Francisco
geoInfo = String.valueOf(status.getGeoLocation().getLatitude()) + "," + String.valueOf(status.getGeoLocation().getLongitude()); //Get the Lat. Long. of the tweet

FilterQuery tweetFilterQuery = new FilterQuery();
 tweetFilterQuery.locations(new double[][]{new double[]{-124.848974,24.396308},new double[]{-66.885444,49.384358}}); //USA Bounding box
```

I finally attach this to the stream where I want to filter

I am attaching my results as a screenshot.

The issues are that I am getting my tweets presumably from the far east as most of the tweet seem to be in Malay.

Secondly how to I set it for Indian coordinates and more specifically for a city in India.

I also want to run a multiple filter where I can get my tweets coming from say Mumbai, and have a particular keyword in them.

Output:

```
58761 [Thread-11-infoBolt] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task - Emitting: infoBolt default [Kukurilingan (at Jalan Selakaso) — https://t.co/HilfQNa7GY, Kukurilingan(atJalanSelakaso)—https://tco/HilfQNa7GY, , , , c2016, https://t.co/HilfQNa7GY, 0, , 0]
58762 [Thread-27-top-words] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Processing received message source: infoBolt:3, stream: default, id: {}, [Kukurilingan (at Jalan Selakaso) — https://t.co/HilfQNa7GY, Kukurilingan(atJalanSelakaso)—https://tco/HilfQNa7GY, , , , c2016, https://t.co/HilfQNa7GY, 0, , 0]
        TopWords    DEBUG Read Values: , , 
        TopWords    DEBUG Read Values: , , , reportSentiment: 0.3999200159968007, URL : https://t.co/HilfQNa7GY
        TopWords    DEBUG EMIT Tweet Kukurilingan (at Jalan Selakaso) — https://t.co/HilfQNa7GY, matcedEmoticon: , sentimentKey: c2016 0, reportSentiment: 0.3999200159968007
58773 [Thread-27-top-words] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.task - Emitting: top-words default [Kukurilingan (at Jalan Selakaso) — https://t.co/HilfQNa7GY, Kukurilingan (at Jalan Selakaso) — https://t.co/HilfQNa7GY, , , , c2016, https://t.co/HilfQNa7GY, 0, , 0.3999200159968007]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it might be helpful to focus on one question at a time. My first observation is unless you didn't put in some code, you are doing things at the top that don't accomplish anything.

You declare `geoInfo`, then immediately try to replace it with the location of the tweet. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

The only thing `tweetFilterQuery` would do is filter in the US, but only if you do add this filter to the stream as you say.

You can set it for a city the same way you have it set for the US, but just change the corners of the long/lat box.

You can make it based on a keyword by adding:

```
`tweetFilterQuery.track(new String[]{searchingPhrase});`
```

*EDIT* Seems that you cannot filter on both location and keyword at the same time. You have to manually search within a string after you have the results.